# Opengraph Action with 2 objects

Tags: facebook, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I have an action, e.g. 'test', and I would like to post with 2 objects, let's say 'objectFoo' and 'objectBaa'

The motive for connecting 2 objects to one action is I would like to create 2 aggregations for one action, each displaying different data.

**Using the Graph API Explorer...**

I can successfully post a '**Test**' action where I add the field '**objectFoo**' is 'http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/opengraph?id=objectFoo'

and

I can successfully post a '**Test**' action where I add the field '**objectBaa**' is 'http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/opengraph?id=objectBaa'

**However** I would like to post an action giving both of these objects.  When I try this I get a code 100 error which reads:
`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Only one of objectFoo, objectBaa reference objects can be specified for type myapp:test.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}`

On the opengraph dashboard, when defining and Action it is possible to connect and action to more than one object in the 'Connected Object Types' field (I wanted to post a screenshot but I'm a newbee here), but as stated I receive an error when testing this.  Is there a bug with the Graph API explorer or is what I am trying to do fundamentally wrong?

Thank you for any feedback

Comment: _“it is possible to connect an action to more than one object in the 'Connected Object Types' field”_ – To more than one object _type_. AFAIK you can not put the same object type in there twice. (You can type it in, but it won’t survive saving these settings.)

Comment: are you trying to use both the object types with given action in same activity post? can share the code snippet which you are using to post the activity?

Comment: “it is possible to connect an action to more than one object in the 'Connected Object Types' field” - I am using two different object types.

Comment: "are you trying to use both the object types with given action in same activity post?" - Yes, the posted action is made with both objects at the same time

Answer (score 2):

using two objects with one action in same post is not possible. For making one activity post you can use just one object with an action though you can use two different object with same action in two different post.

```
//this is not possible(same action with two different object in same post)
$facebook->api("me/app_nameSpace:actionName","POST",array("object1"=>"object1_url","object2"=>"object2_url");

//though you can do this(same action with two diffrent object in two different post)
$facebook->api("me/app_nameSpace:actionName","POST",array("object1"=>"object1_url");
$facebook->api("me/app_nameSpace:actionName","POST",array("object2"=>"object2_url");
```

so you will need to post two seperate action activity like:

```
user created picture
user created game
```

where `create` is action name and `picture` and `game` are two different objects.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  It has become clear to me that indeed, one post with two object references is most definitely not possible, just as Smita states.  It makes sense although it would be very useful to have the option to connect to multiple objects; a visible object (i.e. for posts on the timeline) and non-visible objects that could be used for aggregations.  For my circumstance, ideally I do not want to do two posts because I don't want two feeds posted at the same time, I want one for a feed and aggregation, and one just for an aggregation.

Comment: My solution has been to use 2 different actions.  One with 'no_feed_story' boolean set to true, however I won't be able to determine if this actually works until I am not working on localhost - that's another issue...

Comment: p.s. Smita, I like the idea behind your site, safe child/family oriented social networking